# Python Pandas - convert unicode data into dataframe so I can append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I am pulling data using pytreasurydirect and I would like to query each unique cusip and then append them and create a pandas dataframe table.  I am having difficulties generating the the pandas dataframe.  I believe it is because of the unicode structure of the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from pytreasurydirect import TreasuryDirect
td = TreasuryDirect()

cusip_list = [['912796PY9','08/09/2018'],['912796PY9','06/07/2018']]

for i in cusip_list:
    cusip =''.join(i[0]) 
    issuedate =''.join(i[1])
    cusip_value=(td.security_info(cusip, issuedate))
    #pd.DataFrame(cusip_value.items())
    df = pd.DataFrame(cusip_value, index=['a']) 
    td = td.append(df, ignore_index=False)
```

Example of data from pytreasurydirect :

```
Index([u'accruedInterestPer100', u'accruedInterestPer1000',
       u'adjustedAccruedInterestPer1000', u'adjustedPrice',
       u'allocationPercentage', u'allocationPercentageDecimals',
       u'announcedCusip', u'announcementDate', u'auctionDate',
       u'auctionDateYear',
       ...
       u'totalTendered', u'treasuryDirectAccepted',
       u'treasuryDirectTendersAccepted', u'type',
       u'unadjustedAccruedInterestPer1000', u'unadjustedPrice',
       u'updatedTimestamp', u'xmlFilenameAnnouncement',
       u'xmlFilenameCompetitiveResults', u'xmlFilenameSpecialAnnouncement'],
      dtype='object', length=116)
```

Comment: Can you show how cusip_value looks like? Iteration is not beneficial in pandas.

Comment: The cusip value is = 912796PY9.  This value exists for two different treasury note issues 08/09/2018 and 06/07/2018

Comment: what is this code doing ?`td.security_info(cusip, issuedate))`

Comment: this code is putting together a dataset that contains all of the US national debt by individual bond.  The cusip/issue date is the unique debt key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to define a function like this:

```
def securities(type):
    secs = td.security_type(type)
    keys = secs[0].keys() if secs else []
    seri = [pd.Series([sec[key] for sec in secs]) for key in keys]
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(keys, seri)))
```

Then, use it:

```
df = securities('Bond')
df[['cusip', 'issueDate', 'maturityDate']].head()
```

to get results like these, for example (TreasuryDirect returns a lot of addition columns):

```
       cusip            issueDate         maturityDate
0  912810SD1  2018-08-15T00:00:00  2048-08-15T00:00:00
1  912810SC3  2018-07-16T00:00:00  2048-05-15T00:00:00
2  912810SC3  2018-06-15T00:00:00  2048-05-15T00:00:00
3  912810SC3  2018-05-15T00:00:00  2048-05-15T00:00:00
4  912810SA7  2018-04-16T00:00:00  2048-02-15T00:00:00
```

At least today those are the results today. The results will change over time as bonds are issued and, alas, mature. Note the multiple `issueDates` per `cusip`.

Finally, per the TreasuryDirect website (https://www.treasurydirect.gov/webapis/webapisecurities.htm), the possible security types are: `Bill`, `Note`, `Bond`, `CMB`, `TIPS`, `FRN`.